# Unable to add mamba env to PyCharm due to OK button greyed out

Tags: python, pycharm, conda, mamba

On MacOs using PyCharm `Build #PY-232.8660.197, built on July 26, 2023` I'm unable to add conda env as Python Interpreter because the 'OK' button is grayed out.

The path exist:

```
ls -Gflash /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/mambaforge/base/bin/mam*                                                                                                                                                    ─╯
  8 -rwxrwxr-x  1 mc  admin   247B Apr 11 15:29 /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/mambaforge/base/bin/mamba
840 -rwxrwxr-x  2 mc  admin   420K Mar 28 13:36 /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/mambaforge/base/bin/mamba-package
```

How can I fix this?

EDIT:
It turns out that when I change `mamba` -> `conda` in this path it accepts `conda` .

Still: why mamba is not accepted?

[image]

Comment: The conta executable input is red, seems like there's an error in the path. copy and paste it in the explorer and see if it works.

Comment: @Daviid The path exists I've added the command in my answer that I used to validate.

Comment: Does it show any tooltip error if you hover the path input or the ok button?

Comment: Yes, I've updated the screenshot, but it does not change much i guess.